# Asynchronous Listener Synchronization Java HID

Tags: java, synchronization, listener, hid

I tried to look around for some time, but I was not able to find an answer to my problem.
I am currently writing a Java program that will be used to read and update the firmware of an HID device. I am using the pureHID java libraries to communicate with my device and everything is working fine.

The only problem I am currently experiencing, and I was not able to fix, concerns the synchronization of events.

I will give you an example.
When copying the firmware currently installed on the device, I am using the following method

```
dev.setOutputReport((byte) 0, packet_to_send, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

The answer from the unit will come in the form of an event received by the listener attached to the device manager, namely the following listener will be invoked

```
onInputReport() /* Something will happen */
```

My problem is that SOMETIMES, probably because of concurrent writing/listening invocation, the program completely freeze, without any exception nor any error signaled.

To fix the problem, I tried to implement a simple Lock mechanism, with the Lock being released only when a reply is received; but unfortunately it may happen that the reply packet sometimes is lost thus blocking me in a deadlock.

One possible solution I though would be to use a timer which will release the lock automatically after x milliseconds if it is not released (the reply will arrive within 10ms or will not arrive), but I do not know how to create an independent thread to manage the timer.

Can you please help me fixing this problem, or suggest me another concurrency mechanism which I can use to synchronize the two blocks OR to re-transmit the message, if a reply is lost?

Thank you very much to anyone helping.

Lorenzo